# React hook confusion

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm confused with the useEffect and useState hooks.
I have a page where I load a list of movies using the useEffect hook.
The list displays nicely on my screen. When I want to edit a movie, I click on it, and this sends the ID of that movie to a method where I want to look up the movie in the list of movies in the state, load that movie in a form and present it to be edited.
Now, whenever I want to lookup that movie, the list of movies in my state is empty.
Although it is shown on my screen.
So I wonder what does setMovies do then and how are they shown on the screen but I get an empty array anywhere else?

I used to work with class components where this was no issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MovieList = () => {
    const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
    const [movieToEdit, setMovieToEdit] = useState({});
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const openEditMovie = (movieId) => {
        console.log("movies", movies); // is empty here !?
        setMovieToEdit(movies.find(m => m.id === movieId));
        setOpenEdit(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMovies();
    }, []);

    const fetchMovies = async () => {
        let movies = await axios.get('/movies'); // just sample code, you get the picture
        console.log("movies", movies); // lists movies
        setMovies(movies);
    }

    return (
        <List source={movies}/>
        { /* and the dialog with the form etc go below here */ }
    );
};

export default MovieList;
```

Comment: I am doubting about the variable names, can you change the variable movie to something else?

Comment: Might be worth a read -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html & https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @danialdehvan I'm having a hard time finding a variable called `movie`..

Answer (score 1):

Here a little mock up of your code which seems to do whats expected, so I would check the return value of your axios-call. Can you clarify if your log in the fetchMovie function shows `[object Object]`? I'm asking since you mentioned that it actually lists the movies..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const MovieList = () => {
    const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
    const [movieToEdit, setMovieToEdit] = useState({});
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const openEditMovie = (movieId) => {
        console.log("movieLogEdit:",movies); // not empty
        setMovieToEdit(movies.find(m => m.id === movieId));
        setOpenEdit(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMovies();
    }, []);

    const fetchMovies = async () => {
        let movies = [1,2,4]; // mocked data
        console.log("movieLogFetch:" + movies); // lists movies on initial render since useEffect has [] as second argument
        setMovies(movies);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button className="button is-primary" onClick={openEditMovie}>
          Open Movie Editor
        </button>
      </div>
    );
};

export default MovieList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Just change `setMovies(movies)` to `setMovies(movies.data)` because Axios returns an response object with a property `data` which contains the data sent by the server (API).

```js
const fetchMovies = async () => {
  let movies = await axios.get("/movies");
  console.log("movies", movies.data);
  setMovies(movies.data);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I get your point, but the axios call was just pseudo code. I will however double check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

An answer was found, and I realise by simplifying my code, I had left out the part that caused the problem.
In the `fetchMovies` method, I was constructing an array of values to pass to a Material UI Datatable (https://www.material-ui-datatables.com).

```
const fetchMovies = async () => {
    let movies = await axios.get('/movies'); // just sample code, you get the picture
    console.log("movies", movies); // lists movies
    setMovies(
        movies.map(movie => [
            movie.id, 
            movie.name, 
            movie.year, 
            <EditIcon onClick={() => openEditMovie(movie.id)}/>
        ])
    );
}
```

Now apparently, as I've been told, at the time this array is constructed, the `openEditMovie` function is copied in memory, together with the state as it was at that moment. So when calling the method from the `onClick`, I would always have the old state available, with an empty movies array.
When you call the `openEditMovie` somewhere else from the code later on, I have acces to the updated state.
Never saw that one coming!